# Show a component box on hover like dropdown menu and popup

Tags: css, reactjs

Hello i'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

Basically I wanted to show an icon hover box

code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faSearch,
  faAdjust,
  faUserCircle,
  faAngleDown
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
export default function App() {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

  const updateHover = () => {
    setHover(!hover);
  };

  console.log(hover);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span>
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          className="adjust"
          icon={faAngleDown}
          size="lg"
          fixedWidth
          color="black"
          onMouseOver={updateHover}
        />
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As a popup or dropdown effect to simulate a login box

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: I would like to know how I could make a box like the gif when it's on hover and how I could hide it when it's not on hover

Answer (score 1):

You have the `hover` boolean in the state, so all you need to do now is show or hide a component depending on the value:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span>
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          className="adjust"
          icon={faAngleDown}
          size="lg"
          fixedWidth
          color="black"
          onMouseOver={updateHover}
        />
      </span>
      {hover ? <YourOverlayComponent /> : null}
    </div>
  );
```

Obviously you will need some CSS to make it appear on top like the gif example.

Comment: my biggest problem is with the css i have doubts on how i could get something like that

Comment: I don't know if the best option would be with translate or position absolute ..